# regridding fails in iris due to coordinate system disagreement

Tags: python, interpolation, python-iris

I want to simply regrid one dataset's lat-lon values onto another and it fails with a coordinate mismatch error. Does anyone have any tips for fixing this?

I've put the code and the cube descriptions at the end.

Thanks!

```
>>> esm_height = iris.load_cube('model_data/u-bl658/height.nc')
>>> ncepncar_clusters = iris.load('ncepncar/clusters.nc')
>>> foo = esm_height[0].regrid(ncepncar_clusters[0], iris.analysis.Linear())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-c90265ebff43> in <module>
----> 1 foo = esm_height[0].regrid(ncepncar_clusters[0], iris.analysis.Linear())

/nesi/nobackup/niwa00013/williamsjh/miniconda3/envs/kidson2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iris/cube.py in regrid(self, grid, scheme)
   3802         """
   3803         regridder = scheme.regridder(self, grid)
-> 3804         return regridder(self)
   3805 
   3806 

/nesi/nobackup/niwa00013/williamsjh/miniconda3/envs/kidson2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iris/analysis/_regrid.py in __call__(self, src)
    943                                  "matching coordinate metadata.")
    944         elif src_cs is None or grid_cs is None:
--> 945             raise ValueError("The rectilinear grid coordinates of the given "
    946                              "cube and target grid must either both have "
    947                              "coordinate systems or both have no coordinate "

ValueError: The rectilinear grid coordinates of the given cube and target grid must either both have coordinate systems or both have no coordinate system but with matching coordinate metadata.
```

[cube to be regridded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Zf8.png)
[cube with target grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBrtU.png)

Answer (score 3):

OK with some help I've fixed this now!

It was because the coordinate reference system for both the source and target cubes were not the same.

This fixes the issue...

```
nzesm_height[0].coord(axis='x').coord_system
GeogCS(6371229.0)

nzesm_height[0].coord(axis='y').coord_system
GeogCS(6371229.0)

ncepncar_clusters[0].coord(axis='x').coord_system = esm_height[0].coord(axis='x').coord_system

ncepncar_clusters[0].coord(axis='y').coord_system = esm_height[0].coord(axis='y').coord_system

foo = nzesm_height[0].regrid(ncepncar_clusters[0], iris.analysis.Linear())
```

I hope this helps others!